# How to make radio-group decide the number of input-fields in a group of div's

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a piece of javscript that will decide the number of input-fields (number) in a group of divs, when pressing one of 3 radio buttons. When pressing one of the radio buttons all div's in the group should have two input fields. When pressing the two other radio buttons there should only be one. I've made the following code, but for some reason it only changes the first occurence of the div. The rest of the div's have no input field. See the attached image.

Html is here: https://jsfiddle.net/h07tg5aj/

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var radioContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.form-step .type-window');
  var numberInputContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.form-step .number-input-container');

  console.log("radioContainers:", radioContainers);


  radioContainers.forEach(function (radioContainer, index) {
    var radioButtons = radioContainer.querySelectorAll('input[name="plan"]');
    var numberInputContainer = numberInputContainers[index];

    radioButtons.forEach(function (radioButton) {
      radioButton.addEventListener('change', function () {
        hideAllNumberInputContainers();

        if (radioButton.id === 'etplan') {
          showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainer, 'stue-item');
        } else if (radioButton.id === 'toplan') {
          showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainer, 'stue-item');
          showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainer, 'sal-item');
        } else if (radioButton.id === 'etagelejlighed') {
          showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainer, 'lejlighed-item');
        }
      });
    });
  });

  function hideAllNumberInputContainers() {
    numberInputContainers.forEach(function (container) {
      var inputs = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
      inputs.forEach(function (input) {
        input.style.display = 'none';
      });
    });
  };

  function showNumberInputContainer(container, selector) {
    var inputs = container.getElementsByClassName(selector);
    Array.from(inputs).forEach(function (input) {
      input.style.display = 'inline-block';
    });
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the HTML to your question. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar
Thank you. Updated with jsfidddle

Comment: Why not put it here in Stack Snippet?

Comment: I don't see the form in the jsfiddle. You have lots of `display: none` in the CSS, so everything is invisible.

Comment: In the given JS Fiddle..There are lots of issues in the CSS, fix them first so that we can work on the JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all inputs, you need to pass all inputs in

```
  showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainers, "stue-item");
```

and then to go with all inputs inside that function

function showNumberInputContainer(containers, selector) {

```
      containers.forEach(function (container) {

        var inputs = container.getElementsByClassName(selector);
        Array.from(inputs).forEach(function (input) {
          input.style.display = "inline-block";
        });

      });
    }
```

```js
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var radioContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".form-step .type-window");
        var numberInputContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".number-input-container");
        console.log("radioContainers:", radioContainers);

        radioContainers.forEach(function (radioContainer, index) {
          var radioButtons = radioContainer.querySelectorAll('input[name="plan"]');
          var numberInputContainer = numberInputContainers[index];

          radioButtons.forEach(function (radioButton) {
            radioButton.addEventListener("change", function () {
              hideAllNumberInputContainers();

              if (radioButton.id === "etplan") {
                showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainers, "stue-item");
              } else if (radioButton.id === "toplan") {
                showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainers, "stue-item");
                showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainers, "sal-item");
              } else if (radioButton.id === "etagelejlighed") {
                showNumberInputContainer(numberInputContainers, "lejlighed-item");
              }
            });
          });
        });

        function hideAllNumberInputContainers() {
          numberInputContainers.forEach(function (container) {
            var inputs = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
            inputs.forEach(function (input) {
              input.style.display = "none";
            });
          });
        }

        function showNumberInputContainer(containers, selector) {
            
          containers.forEach(function (container) {

            var inputs = container.getElementsByClassName(selector);
            Array.from(inputs).forEach(function (input) {
              input.style.display = "inline-block";
            });

          });
        }
      });
```

```css
      .container {
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }

      :root {
        --primary-color: #1a7efb;
      }

      *,
      *::before,
      *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      /* Global Stylings */
      label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
      }

      input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.75rem;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
      }

      .width-50 {
        width: 50%;
      }

      .ml-auto {
        margin-left: auto;
      }

      .text-center {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .div-center {
        display: grid;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
        gap: 20px;
        justify-items: center;
      }

      /* Progressbar */
      .progressbar {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        counter-reset: step;
        margin: 0rem 0rem 4rem;
      }

      .progressbar::before,
      .progress {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        height: 4px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
      }

      .progress {
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        width: 0%;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .progress-step {
        width: 2.1875rem;
        height: 2.1875rem;
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      .progress-step::before {
        counter-increment: step;
        content: counter(step);
      }

      .progress-step::after {
        content: attr(data-title);
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(100% + 0.5rem);
        font-size: 0.85rem;
        color: #666;
      }

      .progress-step-active {
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: #f3f3f3;
      }

      /* Form */
      .form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      .form-step {
        /* display: none; */
      }

      .form-step-active {
        display: block;
      }

      .input-group {
        margin: 2rem 0;
      }

      /* Button */
      .btns-group {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        gap: 1.5rem;
      }

      .btn {
        padding: 0.75rem;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: #f3f3f3;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .btn:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 0 3px var(--primary-color);
      }

      /* house */
      .house {
        margin: auto;
        width: 150px;
      }

      .story {
        background-color: grey;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .roof {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 0;
        border-left: 75px solid transparent;
        border-right: 75px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 40px solid black;
      }

      #checkboxes input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
      }

      #checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .story {
        background-color: green;
      }

      /* Style for the radio container */
      .radio-container {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }

      /* Style for the radio button */
      .radio-input {
        display: none;
        /* Hide the actual radio input */
      }

      /* Style for the custom radio button */
      .custom-radio {
        max-width: 250px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 2px solid #3498db;
        padding: 5px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      /* Style for the radio button label */
      .radio-label {
        color: #333;
        user-select: none;
      }

      /* Change background color and show checkmark when radio button is checked */
      .radio-input:checked + .custom-radio {
        background-color: #3498db;
      }

      .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        gap: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .grid-item {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .image-section {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #bbd594; /* Background color matching the image */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .image-section img {
        max-width: 90%; /* Adjust the width to be less than 100% */
        height: auto;
        object-fit: contain; /* Use 'contain' to ensure the image is fully visible */
      }

      .content-section {
        padding: 10px 5px 15px 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: white; /* White background for the content below the image */
      }

      .window-text {
        height: 70px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      /* -- .grid-item > * {
  background: white; 
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin-top: 10px;
} */

      .item-count {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }

      input[type="number"] {
        /*for absolutely positioning spinners*/
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 50px;
        padding-right: 25px;
      }

      input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
      input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
      input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: inner-spin-button !important;
        width: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }

      @media (min-width: 600px) {
        /* For laptops and desktops */
        .grid-container {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
          /* multiple columns layout */
        }
      }
```

```html
    <div class="form-step">
      <div class="input-group"></div>
      <div class="type-window div-center">
        <label class="radio-container">
          <input type="radio" class="radio-input" id="etplan" name="plan" />
          <div class="custom-radio div-center">
            <span class="radio-label">1 plan</span>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-container">
          <input type="radio" class="radio-input" id="toplan" name="plan" />
          <div class="custom-radio">
            <span class="radio-label">2 plan</span>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-container">
          <input type="radio" class="radio-input" id="etagelejlighed" name="plan" />
          <div class="custom-radio">
            <span class="radio-label">Etagelejlighed med ståadgang via altan eller svalegang</span>
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-next width-50 ml-auto">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-step">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="grid-container">
          <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="image-section">
              <img decoding="async" src="https://vinduespudser.dk//wp-content/uploads/2024/01/01vindue1.webp" alt="Vindue 1 rude" />
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
              <div class="window-text">Vindue 1 rude</div>
              <div class="number-input-container">
                <!-- lejlighed -->
                <input type="number" class="lejlighed-item" id="lejlighed-item2Count" name="lejlighed-item2Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="lejlighed-item2Price" name="lejlighed-item2Price" value="127" />
                <!-- 1. sal -->
                <input type="number" class="sal-item" id="sal-item2Count" name="sal-item2Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: inline-block" />
                <input type="hidden" id="sal-item2Price" name="sal-item2Price" value="127" />
                <!-- stue -->
                <input type="number" class="stue-item" id="stue-item2Count" name="stue-item2Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: inline-block" />
                <input type="hidden" id="stue-item2Price" name="stue-item2Price" value="127" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="image-section">
              <img decoding="async" src="https://vinduespudser.dk//wp-content/uploads/2024/01/03vindue4.webp" alt="Vindue 4 ruder" />
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
              <div class="window-text">Vindue 4 ruder</div>
              <div class="number-input-container">
                <!-- lejlighed -->
                <input type="number" class="lejlighed-item" id="lejlighed-item3Count" name="lejlighed-item3Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="lejlighed-item3Price" name="lejlighed-item3Price" value="150" />
                <!-- 1. sal -->
                <input type="number" class="sal-item" id="sal-item3Count" name="sal-item3Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="sal-item3Price" name="sal-item3Price" value="150" />
                <!-- stue -->
                <input type="number" class="stue-item" id="stue-item3Count" name="stue-item3Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="stue-item3Price" name="stue-item3Price" value="150" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="image-section">
              <img decoding="async" src="https://vinduespudser.dk//wp-content/uploads/2024/01/04vinduelille1.webp" alt="Lille vindue" />
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
              <div class="window-text">Lille vindue</div>
              <div class="number-input-container">
                <!-- lejlighed -->
                <input type="number" class="lejlighed-item" id="lejlighed-item4Count" name="lejlighed-item4Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="lejlighed-item4Price" name="lejlighed-item4Price" value="120" />
                <!-- 1. sal -->
                <input type="number" class="sal-item" id="sal-item4Count" name="sal-item4Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="sal-item4Price" name="sal-item4Price" value="120" />
                <!-- stue -->
                <input type="number" class="stue-item" id="stue-item4Count" name="stue-item4Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="stue-item4Price" name="stue-item4Price" value="120" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="image-section">
              <img decoding="async" src="https://vinduespudser.dk//wp-content/uploads/2024/01/07dannebrogsvindue5.webp" alt="Dannebrogsvindue 5 ruder" />
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
              <div class="window-text">Dannebrogsvindue 5 ruder</div>
              <div class="number-input-container">
                <!-- lejlighed -->
                <input type="number" class="lejlighed-item" id="lejlighed-item5Count" name="lejlighed-item5Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="lejlighed-item5Price" name="lejlighed-item5Price" value="127" />
                <!-- 1. sal -->
                <input type="number" class="sal-item" id="sal-item5Count" name="sal-item5Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="sal-item5Price" name="sal-item5Price" value="127" />
                <!-- stue -->
                <input type="number" class="stue-item" id="stue-item5Count" name="stue-item5Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="stue-item5Price" name="stue-item5Price" value="127" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="image-section">
              <img decoding="async" src="https://vinduespudser.dk//wp-content/uploads/2024/01/08dannebrogsvindue6.webp" alt="Dannebrogsvindue 6 ruder" />
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
              <div class="window-text">Dannebrogsvindue 6 ruder</div>
              <div class="number-input-container">
                <!-- lejlighed -->
                <input type="number" class="lejlighed-item" id="lejlighed-item6Count" name="lejlighed-item6Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="lejlighed-item6Price" name="lejlighed-item6Price" value="127" />
                <!-- 1. sal -->
                <input type="number" class="sal-item" id="sal-item6Count" name="sal-item6Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="sal-item6Price" name="sal-item6Price" value="127" />
                <!-- stue -->
                <input type="number" class="stue-item" id="stue-item6Count" name="stue-item6Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="stue-item6Price" name="stue-item6Price" value="127" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="image-section">
              <img decoding="async" src="https://vinduespudser.dk//wp-content/uploads/2024/01/06dannebrogsvindue4.webp" alt="Dannebrogsvindue 4 ruder" />
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
              <div class="window-text">Dannebrogsvindue 4 ruder</div>
              <div class="number-input-container">
                <!-- lejlighed -->
                <input type="number" class="lejlighed-item" id="lejlighed-item7Count" name="lejlighed-item7Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="lejlighed-item7Price" name="lejlighed-item7Price" value="127" />
                <!-- 1. sal -->
                <input type="number" class="sal-item" id="sal-item7Count" name="sal-item7Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="sal-item7Price" name="sal-item7Price" value="127" />
                <!-- stue -->
                <input type="number" class="stue-item" id="stue-item7Count" name="stue-item7Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="stue-item7Price" name="stue-item7Price" value="127" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-item">
            <div class="image-section">
              <img decoding="async" src="https://vinduespudser.dk//wp-content/uploads/2024/01/06dannebrogsvindue4.webp" alt="Bondehus" />
            </div>
            <div class="content-section">
              <div class="window-text">Bondehus</div>
              <div class="number-input-container">
                <!-- lejlighed -->
                <input type="number" class="lejlighed-item" id="lejlighed-item8Count" name="lejlighed-item8Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="lejlighed-item8Price" name="lejlighed-item8Price" value="127" />
                <!-- 1. sal -->
                <input type="number" class="sal-item" id="sal-item8Count" name="sal-item8Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="sal-item8Price" name="sal-item8Price" value="127" />
                <!-- stue -->
                <input type="number" class="stue-item" id="stue-item8Count" name="stue-item8Count" min="0" value="0" style="display: none" />
                <input type="hidden" id="stue-item8Price" name="stue-item8Price" value="127" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btns-group">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-prev">Previous</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-next">Next</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```